# Mixed integer relaxation of bilinear constraint

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization

I have an optimization problem with bilinear constraint, as follows

\begin{align}
\min_{x,s,\lambda} \quad J(x)\\
f(x)=0\\
\lambda^\top x+h(\lambda,x) \leq s\\
\lambda^\top e=1\\
\lambda\geq 0\\
g(\lambda,x)\leq0
\end{align}

where $x \in \mathcal{X} \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $s \in \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{X}$ is a convex set, $e$ is a vector consisting of all ones. In addition, $J(x)$ is a quadratic function, $f(x)$ and $h(\lambda,x)$ are affine functions, $g(\lambda,x)$ is a convex function.

The above optimization problem is nonconvex because of the second constraint. I've tried McCornick relaxation, but it yields to a very loose relaxation.

Is there any way to handle the above problem?

Comment: Did you choose the correct lower and upper bounds for your variables? $lb_i\leq x_i\leq ub_i$ then $0\leq (ub_1-x_1)(ub_2 - x_2)$, $0\leq (x_1 - lb_1)(x_2-lb_2)$, $0\leq (x_1 - lb_1)(ub_2- x_2)$, $0\leq (ub_1-x_2)(x_2-lb_2)$.

Comment: Yes, but in that case I only get a lower bound to the original solution.